# Venn diagrams for 4, 5, and 6 sets in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I'm trying to reproduce the following Venn diagrams in TikZ:

**Venn diagram for 4 sets:**

[image: Venn diagram for 4 sets]

**Venn diagram for 5 sets:**

[image: Venn diagram for 5 sets]

**Venn diagram for 6 sets:**

[image: Venn diagram for 6 sets]

Comment: No offense but these don't look like Venn diagrams anymore, but maybe intellectually some value to some... regarding the drawing you can use the round cap, opacity<1 and draw thick lines with the appropriate blend mode. Or just filled arcs. Note that you don't have a question yet.

Comment: You can try to draw them with geogebra[http://www.geogebra.org/] and export the TikZ code.

Comment: I've always thought of Venn diagrams as a learning tool to aid students in thinking about sets and their interrelations.  The beauty of Venn diagrams lies in their simplicity and ease of understanding.  However, these diagrams (particular for 5 and 6 sets) get increasingly obfuscatory: completely counter to this philosophy.  I would start by asking, `why do I need these diagrams?` and `do these diagrams improve the ability of the reader to understand the material?`

Comment: I agree that this diagrams are not so easy to understand, but we can't do the Venn diagram for 4 sets with convex sets in $R^2$. And here is one interesting question from TikZ point of view : how to draw the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of a path ?

Comment: That sounds like a more interesting question. Have you tried anything with decorations?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you have tried and provides people with something to work from. Making it easy for people to help encourages them to help you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what it should look like (I'm colorblind so everything looks OK to me) but here is the second one. Ifyour viewer can handle it play with the `blend mode` parameter for different effects.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mys/.style={pink!80,fill opacity=0.5,draw=black }]
\begin{scope}[transparency group]
\begin{scope}%[blend mode=hue]
\fill[mys] ( 90:.6) circle (1);
\fill[mys] (210:.6) circle (1);
\fill[mys] (330:.6) circle (1);
\draw[orange,line width=0.5cm,cap=round,opacity=.5] (330:.6) +(-1,0) arc (180:0:1);
\draw[yellow!75!blue,line width=0.25cm,cap=round,opacity=.5] 
(330:.6) +(-0.75,0) arc (180:0:0.75) arc(180:360:0.25) arc (0:180:1.25);
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]